# HTTP request failed on bower angular-card-input install on jenkins build script

Tags: centos, git, jenkins

I am getting a error while running bower script to build a frontend in angular:

> bower angular-ui-utils#bower  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote
>   --tags --heads https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git", exit code of #128 error:  while accessing
>   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git/info/refs  fatal: HTTP
>   request failed

The previous link states:

> "Please upgrade your git client. GitHub.com no longer supports git
>   over dumb-http:
>   https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days"

So, it seems like my machine has an old version of Git client... but 
I just updated (yum update):

- Git client to the current latest version (1.7.1-9)
- jenkins to the currently most recent weekely version (2.109).

and the same error still happens.
More, it shouldn't happen because the github link above says:

> "Starting June 7th, 2011, GitHub will no longer support fetching over
>   Git's "dumb" HTTP transport mechanism. This won't effect you unless
>   you're running a git version prior to v1.6.6 and fetch using a http
>   remote URL."

and my git client version (1.7.x) is higher than the minimum required (1.6.6). So I suppose this can't be the problem.

Does npm or bower have an internal git client that could be outdated?

Any hints on how to fix this problem are very welcome.
Thanks

This is a part of the jenkins build log:

```
+ sudo -E npm update
+ bower install
bower angular-ui-utils extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: angular-ui-utils#bower
+ bower update
bower angular-card-input#*  not-cached https://github.com/OutlawAndy/angular-card-input.git#*
bower angular-card-input#*     resolve https://github.com/OutlawAndy/angular-card-input.git#*
bower angular-ui-utils#bower       not-cached https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#bower
bower angular-ui-utils#bower          resolve https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#bower
bower angular#1.4.8                    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular#1.4.8                  validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular-sanitize#1.4.8           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.4.8
bower angular-sanitize#1.4.8         validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.4.8
bower font-awesome#~4.2.0              cached https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.2.0
bower font-awesome#~4.2.0            validate 4.2.0 against https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.2.0
bower json3#~3.3.1                     cached https://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.3.2
bower json3#~3.3.1                   validate 3.3.2 against https://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.3.1
bower angular-resource#1.4.8           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.8
bower angular-resource#1.4.8         validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.8
bower es5-shim#~4.0.3                  cached https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#4.0.6
bower es5-shim#~4.0.3                validate 4.0.6 against https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~4.0.3
bower angular-bootstrap-show-errors#*  cached https://github.com/paulyoder/angular-bootstrap-show-errors.git#2.3.0
bower angular-bootstrap-show-errors#*         validate 2.3.0 against https://github.com/paulyoder/angular-bootstrap-show-errors.git#*
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.11                 cached https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower.git#0.2.18
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.11               validate 0.2.18 against https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower.git#~0.2.11
bower ngstorage#~0.3.6                          cached https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.git#0.3.11
bower ngstorage#~0.3.6                        validate 0.3.11 against https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.git#~0.3.6
bower angular-translate-handler-log#~2.8.0      cached https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-handler-log.git#2.8.1
bower angular-translate-handler-log#~2.8.0    validate 2.8.1 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-handler-log.git#~2.8.0
bower angular-translate#~2.8.0                  cached https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#2.8.1
bower angular-translate#~2.8.0                validate 2.8.1 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#~2.8.0
bower famfamfam-flags-sprite#~1.0.0             cached https://github.com/atelierspierrot/famfamfam-flags-sprite.git#1.0.0
bower famfamfam-flags-sprite#~1.0.0           validate 1.0.0 against https://github.com/atelierspierrot/famfamfam-flags-sprite.git#~1.0.0
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.11.2                 cached https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.11.2
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.11.2               validate 0.11.2 against https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#~0.11.2
bower moment-timezone#~0.4.1                    cached https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone.git#0.4.1
bower moment-timezone#~0.4.1                  validate 0.4.1 against https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone.git#~0.4.1
bower angular-moment#~0.9.0                     cached https://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#0.9.2
bower angular-moment#~0.9.0                   validate 0.9.2 against https://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#~0.9.0
bower moment#~2.9.0                             cached https://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.9.0
bower moment#~2.9.0                           validate 2.9.0 against https://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.9.0
bower jstzdetect#~1.0.6                         cached https://github.com/HenningM/jstimezonedetect.git#1.0.6
bower jstzdetect#~1.0.6                       validate 1.0.6 against https://github.com/HenningM/jstimezonedetect.git#~1.0.6
bower angular-messages#1.4.8                    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.4.8
bower angular-messages#1.4.8                  validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.4.8
bower angular-mocks#1.4.8                       cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.4.8
bower angular-mocks#1.4.8                     validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.4.8
bower angular-scenario#1.4.8                    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.4.8
bower angular-scenario#1.4.8                  validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.4.8
bower angular-ui-utils#bower                   ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git", exit code of #128 error:  while accessing https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git/info/refs  fatal: HTTP request failed

Additional error details:
error:  while accessing https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[WARNINGS] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Above I say "Git client to the current latest version (1.7.1-9)" - that is the latest version on my CentOs repo.

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same problem on our jenkins server.  We tried:

- updating git
- `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`
- .bowerrc "shorthand-resolver" pattern

nothing worked.

What appeared to resolve things was upgrading nss libcurl and curl - basically the SSL support libraries on the (old) jenkins box.  Again, the theory is is related to GitHub's recent DDOS resolution will require SSL updates on client end.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue just a little while ago. We fixed it by making sure our support libraries (nss, libcurl, openssl, etc) were updated and then updating to the latest version of git. We compiled git from source since the package from the repo we are using was quite a few versions behind.